# Scala's class to Java

Tags: java, android, scala

Please help me with this Scala's class I want to implement it on Java here it is:

```
class StretchVideoView(context:Context, attr:AttributeSet)
extends VideoView(context, attrib) {
    def measure(measureSpec:Int):Int = {
        val specMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec)
        View.MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec)
    }

    override def onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec:Int, heightMeasureSpec:Int) {
        val (w,h) = (measure(widthMeasureSpec), measure(heightMeasureSpec))
        getHolder().setFixedSize(w,h)
       super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    }
}
```

I also tried to do it myself here is my Java code:

```
class StretchVideoView extends VideoView {

        public StretchVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public int measure(int measureSpec) {
        int specMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec)
        ??? View.MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec); // may be + here ???

        return specMode;  // ???
    }

        // and I'm not sure about this
    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {    
        int w = measure(widthMeasureSpec);
        int h = measure(heightMeasureSpec);
        getHolder().setFixedSize(w,h);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);   
    }
}
```

Any suggestions how to implement it on Java?

Here's the original article with this code:
[original code](http://makerwannabe.blogspot.com/2012/02/androids-videoview-doesnt-always.html)

Comment: `return View.MeasuresSpect.getSize(..)` and "it's fine".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this for `measure`:

```
public int measure(int measureSpec) {
    int specMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec)
    return View.MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);
}
```

Comment: thanks but how about the specMode variable? I just return `View.MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec)` using your code it's weird.

Comment: That's what the scala code you posted is doing. So yeah, the scala code is kinda weird too.